# Apple incorrectly regards an in-app purchase as already subscribed

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit, swiftystorekit

I am working on an in-app purchase for an app which is already live. App name is suppose TestApp, I implemented in app purchase in it and suppose user subscribes to a auto renewing subscription from his iTunes id (let's say itunes@example.com) to buy auto renewing subscription having id “com.subscription.example” for his app which is logged in via his personal account (personal@gmail.com).

His iTunes email id and personal email id is different here. Everything works fine and payment is done and then I update accordingly and hit respective APIs.

Now the issue: if he logs into his app from his friend’s email id suppose “friend@gmail.com” and buys the subscription (“com.subscription.example”) for him using his same apple id (i.e itunes@example.com) on purchase Apple will say that this product is already subscribed and will go into the success block of purchase payment function, and then all the API etc will be hit accordingly so a new subscription will be active on his friend’s account without any payment. What can be done?

This is the function I'm using for purchase payment (I'm using swiftystorekit), it only needs purchase ID as parameters.

```
  func purchaseProduct(id: String) {
if self.canMakePurchases() {
  UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
  purchaseButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
  purchaseButton.alpha = 0.6
  NVActivityIndicatorPresenter.sharedInstance.startAnimating(activityData)
  purchaseButton.setTitle("Please wait..", for: .normal)
  SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct(id, quantity: 1, atomically: true) { result in
    NVActivityIndicatorPresenter.sharedInstance.stopAnimating()
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    self.purchaseButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.purchaseButton.setTitle("Purchase", for: .normal)
    self.purchaseButton.alpha = 1
    switch result {
    case .success(let purchase):
      print("Purchase Success: \(purchase.productId)")
      let transactionId = purchase.transaction.transactionIdentifier
      self.createSubscription(status:"active",transID : transactionId!)
    case .error(let error):
      self.createSubscription(status: "not_subscribed",transID:"")
      switch error.code { 
      case .unknown: print("Unknown error. Please contact support")
      case .clientInvalid: print("Not allowed to make the payment")
      case .paymentCancelled: break
      case .paymentInvalid: print("The purchase identifier was invalid")
      case .paymentNotAllowed: print("The device is not allowed to make the payment")
      case .storeProductNotAvailable: print("The product is not available in the current storefront")
      case .cloudServicePermissionDenied: print("Access to cloud service information is not allowed")
      case .cloudServiceNetworkConnectionFailed: print("Could not connect to the network")
      case .cloudServiceRevoked: print("User has revoked permission to use this cloud service")
      }
    }
  }
} else {
  UIAlertView(title: "Sorry",
              message: "Purchases are disabled in your device!",
              delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
}
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: thanks for editing @halfer

Comment: You should check out the WWDC 2018 session on engineering subscriptions for iOS. They cover numerous edge cases and go over the structures and approaches for server-driven subscriptions: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/705/

Comment: Your question title is incorrect. The subscription is already purchased; Apple only knows about Apple IDs, not your account system. You will need to use the original transaction details from the receipt to identify that this subscription is already associated with another account and either not activate the subscription for this account or remove the active state for the subscription on the other account.